# Model property immediately deallocated after being set from JSON

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, properties

After setting a NSString property on my model, it is immediately being returned as Null. What is strange is that setting any typedef properties do get retained (i.e. NSInteger). Code is below. I am also running this method via GCD-but I commented this out & it did not change anything. I also have some NSCoding methods in the model, but commenting out the delegate  didn't change anything.

Literally everything is working, including accessing the JSON dict and NSLogging results, EXCEPT for setting my model properties that aren't typedef.

**Update**

Assigning any NSString to [dictionary valueForKey:@"first_name"] returns Null so clearly    this is a problem accessing the dictionary.

**Update 2**

After logging the dictionary, I'm noticing  that some keyss don't have "" and some values don't have "". I'm using as_json from rails, and in postman chrome extension this DOESNT happen

```
{
available = 1;
boxing = 0;
certificates = "";
city = A;
"created_at" = "2014-12-14T07:23:35.445Z";
description = "Short description";
"drivers_license" = CA12345;
"drivers_license_expiration" = "12/20";
"drivers_license_state" = CA;
email = "test4@aol.com";
"facebook_id" = "";
"first_name" = TEsty;
gender = "";
id = 1;
"last_name" = Again;
latitude = "<null>";
longitude = "<null>";
password = g;
pilates = 0;
"reset_password_token" = "<null>";
running = 0;
strength = 0;
"updated_at" = "2014-12-25T08:42:27.122Z";
yoga = 0;
}
```

.h file

```
@interface FSTrainer : NSObject <NSCoding>

@property (nonatomic) NSInteger id;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* first_name;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* last_name;

- (id) init;
- (id) initWith:(NSMutableDictionary *)dictionary;
```

etc..

.m File

```
-(id)init{
 self = [super init];
 if (!self) return nil;
 return self;
}

- (id) initWith:(NSMutableDictionary *)dictionary
{
 self = [super init];
 if (!self) return nil;


  if ([dictionary valueForKey:@"id"] != [NSNull class])
    {self.id = [[dictionary valueForKey:@"id"] integerValue];}

  if ([dictionary valueForKey:@"first_name"] != [NSNull class])
    {
        [self setFirst_name:[dictionary valueForKey:@"first_name"]];

        NSLog(@"%@", [dictionary objectForKey:@"first_name"]);
        NSLog(@"%@", [dictionary valueForKey:@"first_name"]);}
        //Both NSLogs print out the correct names

  if ([dictionary valueForKey:@"last_name"] != [NSNull class])
    {self.last_name = [valueForKey objectForKey:@"last_name"];}

 etc.... 

return self;
}
```

This is getting called by:

```
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^{
        [self computationForRails];
    });
```

And the function

```
-(void)computationForRails{
...
    FSTrainer* currentTrainer = [[FSTrainer alloc] initWith:[tempdict    valueForKey:@"data"]];
    //sol-added JNKeychian
    [JNKeychain saveValue:currentTrainer forKey:@"current_trainer"];
}
```

Where tempdict equals (data is a key in the dictionary)

```
    id jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: data
                                                    options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                                      error: &error];
```

Where I am accessing the model later (the model I save doesn't set its properties correctly so this is where the app crashes

```
    FSTrainer* current_trainer = [JNKeychain loadValueForKey:@"current_trainer"];
    NSString* trainerName = current_trainer.first_name;
```

Comment: How do you know the property is getting deallocated? Can you show that work please?

Comment: @AaronBrager it is not being deallocated. I posted that when I was still debugging the problem. The property is never being set. I tried to set a temp NSString to the dicitonary value and it returns null. BUT when i nslog value for key (first_name), it logs out correctly. I'm assuming its the way the dict is set up. See my updates and I'll try to update the title

Comment: What do you mean? Property setters are `void` methods. Can you show how you're trying to access the variable?

Comment: @AaronBrager sorry-what I'm trying to say is that after setting the property equal to the [dictionary valueForKey:@"first_name"] it returns null. However when I NSLog(%@, [dictionary objectForKey:@"first_name"]) is logs the correct string. Really strange. Look at the dictionary json that I returned. Some keys have "" others do not. Same goes for values.

Comment: The keys and values with spaces or special characters have quotes. That's normal - it's just how dictionaries and arrays are printed.

Comment: Also, why are you using `valueForKey:` instead of `objectForKey:`?

Comment: @AaronBrager I tried both neither are working. Regardless both work for NSLogging just not when trying to set any NSString*

Comment: You still haven't shown how you're trying to retrieve the values after they're set.

Comment: @AaronBrager I looked at the debugger, and I also included this above at the end:     FSTrainer* current_trainer = [JNKeychain loadValueForKey:@"current_trainer"];
    NSString* trainerName = current_trainer.first_name;

Comment: @AaronBrager I think this is a larger problem, because I'm seeing random inabilities to set other generic temp NSString* in other methods. I am running this on dispatch_async and the URL method is being called from the app delegate. This is a really strange bug & happy to share code

Comment: @AaronBrager I tried screenshotting debugger, but cannot post due to reputation. But I noticed something strange, that all allocated objects before being set have the value next to their pointer equal to their memory address. I.e. NSString tempstring in the debugger equals 0xe5e5e etc.

Comment: The debugger view is unreliable. What happens if you type `po current_trainer.first_name` at the `(lldb)` prompt?

Comment: @AaronBrager wow, it shows the correct name TESty. I don't get it !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your code

```
[self setFirst_name:[dictionary valueForKey:@"first_name"]];
```

with this code

```
[self setFirst_name:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dictionary valueForKey:@"first_name"]]];
```

Its work for me

Comment: Happy holidays ! Unfortunately that did not work, though when I NSlogged that it did log out the correct value. This is very strange.

Comment: @DaynaJuliana - Can you share your code to me please? So, I can check the problem by debuging your code.

Comment: Actually this did work for other values that were coming in strange. Issue was how I was accessing them. Thanks !